# Bash find: exec in reverse oder

Tags: bash, recursion, find

I am iterating over files like so:

```
find $directory -type f -exec codesign {} \;
```

Now the problem here is that files on a higher hierarchy are signed first.
Is there a way to iterate over a directory tree and handle the deepest files first?

So that

```
/My/path/to/app/bin
```

is handled before

```
/My/path/mainbin
```

Comment: sorry, that is supposed to be -type f. thanks for the great and fast answer!

Comment: See my Perl answer for possible problem with `-depth` (don't know if if affects your use-case). M Nejat Aydin's solution is equivalent but doesn't need Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just use [`-depth`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> -depth
>
> The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause descent of the directory hierarchy to be done so that all entries in a directory are acted on before the directory itself. If a -depth primary is not specified, all entries in a directory shall be acted on after the directory itself. If any -depth primary is specified, it shall apply to the entire expression even if the -depth primary would not normally be evaluated.

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p top/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ find top -print
top
top/a
top/a/b
top/a/b/c
top/a/b/c/d
top/a/b/c/d/e
top/a/b/c/d/e/f
top/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
top/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ find top -depth -print
top/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
top/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
top/a/b/c/d/e/f
top/a/b/c/d/e
top/a/b/c/d
top/a/b/c
top/a/b
top/a
top
```

Note that at a particular level, ordering is still arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

Using `find`'s `-depth` option as my other answer, or naive sort as some others, only ensures that sub-directories of a directory are processed before the directory itself, but not that the deepest level is processed first.

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p top/a/b/d/f/h top/a/c/e/g
$ find top -depth -print
top/a/c/e/g
top/a/c/e
top/a/c
top/a/b/d/f/h
top/a/b/d/f
top/a/b/d
top/a/b
top/a
top
```

For overall deepest level to be processed first, the ordering should be something like:

```
top/a/b/d/f/h
top/a/c/e/g
top/a/b/d/f
top/a/c/e
top/a/b/d
top/a/c
top/a/b
top/a
top
```

To determine this ordering, the entire list must be known, and then the number of levels (ie. `/`) of each path counted to enable ranking.

A simple-ish Perl script (assigned to a shell function for this example) to do this ordering is:

```
$ dsort(){
    perl -ne '
        BEGIN { $/ = "\0" } # null-delimited i/o

        $fname[$.] = $_;
        $depth[$.] = tr|/||;

        END {
            print
                map { $fname[$_] }
                sort { $depth[$b] <=> $depth[$a] }
                keys @fname 
        }
    '
}
```

Then:

```
$ find top -print0 | dsort | xargs -0 -I@ echo @
top/a/b/d/f/h
top/a/c/e/g
top/a/b/d/f
top/a/c/e
top/a/b/d
top/a/c
top/a/b
top/a
top
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU utilities, and decorate-sort-undecorate pattern (aka Schwartzian transform):

```
find . -type f -printf '%d %p\0' |
    sort -znr                    |
    sed -z 's/[0-9]* //'         |
    xargs -0 -I@ echo codesign @
```

Drop the `echo` if the output looks ok.

Comment: @jhnc True. That version is more readable. I've modified the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Schwartzian transform without any Perl :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about sorting the output of `find` in descending order:

```
while IFS= read -d "" -r f; do
    codesign "$f"
done < <(find "$directory" -type f -print0 | sort -zr)
```

- `<(command ..)` is a process substitution which feeds the output
  of the `command` to the `read` command in `while` loop via the redirect.
- `-print0`, `sort -z` and `read -d ""` combo uses a null character
  as a file delimiter. It is useful to protect filenames which include
  special characters such as whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a native way in `find`, but you may pipe the output of it into a loop and process it line by line as you wish this way:

```
find . | while read file; do echo filename: "$file"; done
```

In your case, if you are happy just reversing the output of `find`, you may go with something like:

```
find $directory -type f | tac | while read file; do codesign "$file"; done
```